# Map MacVim (mvim) movement keys in iTerm2

Tags: macos, macvim, iterm, iterm2

This question has been asked in various forms and there are a few blog posts around the net but I can't seem to find one that works consistently. I'm going to ask it for my (and perhaps other's) sanity sake :)

I am trying to replicate the arrow movement actions that you see in mvim within iTerm2. The primary ones are listed below. there could be more that I will undoubtedly forget.

---

## Left / Right

**⌘** + **← (command/cmd + arrow left)** - move to the beginning of the line

**⌘** + **→ (command/cmd + arrow right)** - move to the end of the line

**⇧** + **← (shift + arrow left)** - move to the beginning of the word

**⇧** + **→ (shift + arrow right)** - move to the beginning of the word

## Up / Down

**⌘** + **↑ (command/cmd + arrow up)** - move to the beginning of the file

**⌘** + **↓ (command/cmd + arrow down)** - move to the end of the file

**⇧** + **↑ (shift + arrow up)** - move to up 20% (i think??)

**⇧** + **↓ (shift + arrow down)** - move down 20% (something like that?)

---

If you know of more, please let me know and I'll add them to the question.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I would **not** try tp bind the <kbd>cmd</kbd> key outside any GUI application - But it can be done with iTerm2.

Let's get to the easier things first- You should proabably create some kind of testing environment:

- Open up the iTerm2 configuration
- Navigate to `Profiles`.
- Select your current profile
- Click `Other Actions` and then `Duplicate Profile`.

Actiate your new Profile, navigate to the `Keys` section and remove *all* references to <kbd>Shift</kbd> and your arrow key. If you launch a new Shell with this profile the Shift-Arrow combination should already work.

I've set my $TERM to xterm and there are a lot of other *things* which could influence the key mapping, but I've tried this and it worked:

- Add a new entry within the tab `Keys`
- Press your <kbd>cmd</kbd>-Arrow combination
- As `Action` you must select `Send Escape Sequences`
- Add the correct sequence

```
CMD-Up:    [1;5H 
CMD-Down:  [1;5F 
CMD-Left:  [1~
CMD:Right: [4~
```

---

iTerm2 will automatically prepend the Escape key `^[`, so your config should look like this:
[image: Screenshot of the Keys tab]

Comment: I apologize, for whatever reason this didn't show up in my stack alerts. This worked, but it only seems to work in vim. It doesn't work in the normal command mode or rails console. Any ideas?

Comment: I set my $TERM to xterm (from xterm-new) and still couldn't get it to cooperate. SHIFT+up prints A, down B, right C, left D. cmd + left/right move 1 character, cmd + up/down alert with no result

Comment: Same as Chance here.

Comment: Did you map the escape sequences to the correct action? For example in zsh: `bindkey bindkey '^[[1~' backward-word`